# Query in SQL2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

How to drop a Particular column in a Table?

Comment: Try to Accept the answer that is right for you!
and u could have done it in the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690403/query-in-sql2000

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (column_a INT, column_b VARCHAR(20) NULL);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable DROP COLUMN column_b;
GO
EXEC sp_help MyTable;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable;
GO
```